# WPF application crashes on window close

Tags: wpf, crash, window

I've been researching this problem for the last couple of weeks, nearly full time but to no avail. Our WPF application crashes on a window close rather than on startup or hanging after startup.

The details:

- We have a .NET Framework 4 WPF application that runs on at least one computer but crashes on at least another two.
- At first we thought it was a problem in our WCF services or user's file/folder permissions. File/folder permissions were confirmed to be at least create-folder/new-file/edit-file/delete-file, which is sufficient for our purposes.
- The two computers where the application crashes have Windows 7 SP1. One has 32-bit and the other has 64-bit Windows.
- The computers run English Windows 7 with Chinese (Taiwan/Hong Kong) language packs so they must be the Ultimate or Enterprise editions.
- The computers in question are Toshiba laptops. The 32-bit one has i5-3320M 2.6GHz CPU, 4GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 4000 and 2 monitors, including the laptop one.
- An empty WPF application (in VS: New Project > WPF Application > OK > Build) elicits very similar crashes to the full application when empty's main window is closed by clicking [X].
- A utility application, also WPF, which checks WCF service connections, runs service detection correctly but crashes on window close:

[image: UtilityAppCrash]
<sub>(source: [kynetec.com](http://www.kynetec.com/temp/UtilityAppCrash.jpg))</sub>

Here are copies of typical error reports (translated by Google to English), this also happens for all combinations of NET 4/4.5, VS 2010/2/3, anyCPU/x86 EXEs of the empty app:

```
Problem signature: 
Problem Event Name: BEX 
Application Name: EmptyWpfApp2010 (anyCPU NET4) exe. 
Application Version: 1.0.0.0 
Application time stamp: 531dc770 
Error Module Name: StackHash_5949
Error Module Version: 0.0.0.0
Error module timestamp: 00000000 
Exception Offset: 00620066 
Exception Code: c0000005 
Exception Information: 00000008 
Operating System Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
Locale ID: 1028 
Additional Information 1: 5949 
Additional Information 2: 5949acb04a151ed1e962b41b4fd1d537 
Additional Information 3: 0074 
Additional Information 4: 00740617bbd2cb9521eb8c985e373025
```

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BEX 
Application Name: EmptyWpfApp2013 (x86 NET4) exe. 
Application Version: 1.0.0.0 
Application time stamp: 531de903 
Error Module Name: StackHash_5949
Error Module Version: 0.0.0.0 
Error module timestamp: 00000000 
Exception Offset: 00640031 
Exception Code: c0000005 
Exception Information: 00000008 
Operating System Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48 
Locale ID: 1028 
Additional Information 1: 5949 
Additional Information 2: 5949acb04a151ed1e962b41b4fd1d537 
Additional Information 3: 0074 
Additional Information 4: 00740617bbd2cb9521eb8c985e373025
```

I've tried:

- Reinstalling the .NET Framework 4. And applying updates.
- Reinstalling the application as Administrator.
- Running the application as Administrator.
- Running the application in "Windows XP SP3" compatibility mode for all users.
- Excluded the application's setup EXE from DEP and reinstalled, using the set of steps found at the end of this post: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/cannot-disable-dep-for-certain-programs/d5352d1e-11ac-4254-ad3f-c0ecb85311f0
- Kaspersky's TDSSKiller detected no threats.
- HiJackThis detected no threats as far as I can tell (log can be posted, if required).
- Installer for hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976038 does not apply.
- As far as I can tell "Toshiba Book Reader" is not installed.
- In the Registry, TrueType fonts don't have invalid path characters (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts).
- Updated Toshiba graphics driver does not help.

I'm at a loss. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Given that these are both laptops, from a specific vendor, I'd recommend looking into graphics driver upgrades.  My experience is most "random" WPF crash/strangeness ties to graphics driver issues.

Comment: The graphics driver in use is:
2012/3/26
8.15.10.2712

Would you suggest updating from the Toshiba or the Intel site?

Comment: [would this help you?](http://manski.net/2011/06/wpf-crashes-on-exit/)

Comment: @Ruutsa I don't know details of that driver/hardware, but I typically start with the vendor drivers (toshiba), and if they don't work try the hardware company (intel).

Comment: @voddy - I have seen that article while researching. It does not help. When the completely empty WPF application crashes, we do not get a stack trace only Windows application crash dialog.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - I have advised the user to install the latest driver from the Toshiba website. I'll post the results as soon as I hear anything. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - Updated Toshiba graphics driver does not help. Exception Code and Information are the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Exception Code: c0000005 looks like an access violation. Try to catch the exception and try to log it, maybe it tells you some details about the cause:

- Subscribe to the [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.100).aspx) event
- Subscribe to the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.100).aspx) event
- Set legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy in app.config to true, otherwise you can't catch native exceptions in .NET 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - they will be very useful the next time this happens. In the end the user solved the problem but never told us how.

Comment: We suspect some drivers or the OS were updated. This happened only once in the 3 years since the application was released to a 1000+ users.  At least on one of their machines, the application executed correctly but we never got the chance to see the configuration.